# Oracle Clob column export into a .msg file

Tags: file, clob, msg

I have managed to create two procedure for exporting clob data to .msg file - But for some reason all the clob data is not been exported to the file - Not sure what to do - Any help

```
Declare
   Cursor c_emp_files
      is
    SELECT id, clob_content
            FROM table;
            
Begin

   for c in c_emp_files loop
      clob_to_file('c:\temp\', 'F'||c.file_id||'.msg', c.clob_content);
   end loop;
End;
```

```
create or replace PROCEDURE blob_to_file (i_dir IN VARCHAR2,
                                          i_file_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                                          i_clob   IN CLOB)
AS



   l_file       UTL_FILE.file_type;
   l_buffer     RAW (32767);
   l_amount     BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
   l_pos        INTEGER := 1;
   l_blob_len   INTEGER;
 
BEGIN
   l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength (i_clob);
  
   l_file :=
      UTL_FILE.fopen (i_dir,
                      i_file_name,
                      'WB',
                      32767);

   WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len
   LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.read (i_clob,
                     l_amount,
                     l_pos,
                     l_buffer);
      UTL_FILE.put_raw (l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
    
    
      l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
   END LOOP;

   UTL_FILE.fclose (l_file);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      IF UTL_FILE.is_open (l_file)
      THEN
         UTL_FILE.fclose (l_file);
      END IF;
END blob_to_file;
```

I am getting file output as excepted but I couldn't open the file - I guess it is not exporting full content

Answer (score 0):

After some friends help I found the below: their is a procedure in place already in Oracle - which can convert Colb2file - This worked perfectly in Oracle 11g

[Clob2file procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.html#GUID-EDCA522A-88C6-4D4E-8B77-9244587E12F6)

reference from [link](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16814826/#Comment_16814826)

Example code:

```
Declare
   Cursor c_emp_files
      is
    SELECT id, clob_data        
    FROM table;
            
Begin
    -- it will loop the whole emp_files table 

   for c in c_emp_files loop
  
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(c.clob_data,'c:\temp\',c.file_id||'.msg');
    
   end loop;
End;
```